# How to find the longest string object in an arrayList

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

Here is is my problem, I have to explain a lot, because it's a quite complicated.

I have created an arrayList<**Word**>, that contains strings as objects. In my case, I have three classes, all working together, that is supposed to represent a dictionary.

The first class is called "Word", it has a constructor, and has simple methodes like .length, adds 1 to the counter, and keeps track of the words that are repeated.

The second class is called "Wordlist", and uses more advanced methodes like reading a file,  a summary of 30,000 words. Some methodes is for instance, to add words to the arraylist, as objects. Methods like search if they can find a perticular word. Now, these tasks contains parametres, with variables that I can use.

But I came upon a task in which I had to find the longest word(string) in the arrayList, without any parameters. The method is called: public **Word** findLongest().

In the thrid class, I have the test case, where I use the methodes. The most central part here is to read the file, and add it to the arrayList object. In what way can I use the method to find the longest word(string) in the arrayList without any parameters?

It is very confusing with arrayList as objects.

I am aware of the *for (each : array)* use in this sense, but have no idea how use it properly.

Comment: Can you please share the code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Word` class provides a `length()` method which simply returns the length of the word represented by that object, then you can run through your `ArrayList<Word>` and find the longest like this:

```
private Word getLongestWordFromList(List<Word> listOfWords) {
    Word longestWord = null;
    for (Word word : listOfWords) {
        if (longestWord == null || word.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = word;
        }
    }
    return longestWord;
}
```

The `for (Word word : listOfWords)` pattern simply says: iterate through the List called "listOfWords" and store the current Word object in a variable called "word". Then you just check the length of each word to see whether it is longer than the longest already found. (If the `longestWord` variable is `null` then it means you haven't processed any words so far, so whatever is the first Word found will go into that variable, ready to be compared with the next.)

*Note*: if there is more than one word with the longest length then this method will simply return the first word which is found with that length. If you need to return a list of all words having the longest length then you'll need to modify this pattern to generate a `List<Word>` which contains all words of the longest length.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *Word* class has a method called *length()*, maybe something like this:

```
Word longest = arrayList.get(0);
for (int i=1; i<arrayList.size(); ++i) {
   if (arrayList.get(i).length() > longest.length()) {
      longest = arrayList.get(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java Stream enthusiasts one very declarative solution is:

```java
private Word getLongestWordFromList(List<Word> listOfWords) {

    return listOfWords.stream()
        .filter(word -> word != null)
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Word::length))
        .orElse(null);

}
```

`filter` makes sure the stream skips over null values.

`max` compares the word lengths and returns an `Optional<Word>` with the largest length value. Note that instead of `Word::length` we could have also written `word -> word.length()`.

`orElse` "unpacks" the optional value. If it didn't find anything (eg. because every value is `null` or `listOfWords` is empty), it returns `null`.